# How to share common memory in armadillo?

Tags: c++, armadillo

In armadillo, the advanced constructor provide the way to share memory like

```
mat B(10,10);

mat A(B.memptr(),2,50,false, true);
```

but in c++ program about class, one should first declare variables in head file,like

```
mat A,B;
```

and realize other things in cpp file.

So,  anyone can tell me how to share memory between mat A and mat B in cpp file with the declaration of mat A and B in head file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ***vs 2013***,

***#define ARMA_USE_CXX11***

should be included. And then ***std::move*** would work.

Thanks **hbrerkere** for guiding right way.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the `B` matrix as reference the `A` matrix when declaring your class.  For example:

```
class foo
   {
   public:

   mat  A;
   mat& B;  // alias of A

   foo()
     : B(A)  // need to initialize the reference as part of the constructor
     {
     A.zeros(4,5);
     A(1,1) = 1;
     B(2,2) = 2;

     A.print("A:");
     B.print("B:");
     }
   };
```

Another (more brittle) solution is to use a common matrix, then assign the memory to other matrices using C++11 [std::move()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move). For example:

```
#include <utility>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main()
  {
  mat C(4,5, fill::zeros);  // C is the common matrix

  mat A:
  mat B;      

  A = std::move( mat(C.memptr(), C.n_rows, C.n_cols, false, false) );
  B = std::move( mat(C.memptr(), C.n_rows, C.n_cols, false, false) );

  // note: in the above, the last argument of 'false' is important

  A(1,1) = 1;
  B(2,2) = 2;

  // A and B will both have 1 and 2 as they're using the same memory      

  A.print("A:");
  B.print("B:");
  }
```

If you're using gcc or clang, you can enable C++11 mode with the `-std=c++11` switch.

Comment: The second version is more preferred, but it does not work in my vs 2013.
indeed, I want to at will share memory with declared armadillo matrix.
Sir, you can compile the code and run it. I hope it was my fault.

Comment: the VS 2013 compiler is full of bugs, especially its C++11 mode. i recommend that you use a sane compiler that properly supports the C++ standard (for example, gcc or clang)