# Using RcppArmadillo with bigmemory, returning a bigmatrix

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo, r-bigmemory

I'm trying to do some operations with `big.matrix` using `RcppArmadillo` .
The problem is that I always need to keep my results as `big.matrix` avoiding to load data in RAM. This is my code where I create the transpose of a `big.matrix`:

**big_T.cpp**

```
#define ARMA_NO_DEBUG

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo, BH, bigmemory)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

#include <bigmemory/BigMatrix.h>
#include <bigmemory/MatrixAccessor.hpp>

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]


// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool BigArmaT(SEXP pBigMat,SEXP pBigMat_t) {

  XPtr<BigMatrix> xpMat(pBigMat);
  XPtr<BigMatrix> xpMat_t(pBigMat_t);
int NN(xpMat->ncol());
int MM(xpMat->nrow());

arma::Mat<double> aBigMat((double *)xpMat->matrix(), xpMat->nrow(), xpMat->ncol(), false);
arma::Mat<double> tBigMat(aBigMat.t());

MatrixAccessor<double> Am(*xpMat_t);

for (int i = 0; i < MM; i++){
std::memcpy(Am[i],tBigMat.colptr(i) , NN*sizeof(double));
}


  return TRUE;

}
```

**R:**

```
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppArmadillo)
library(bigmemory)

Sys.setenv(PATH="%PATH%;C:/Rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin;c:/Rtools/bin")

sourceCpp("big_T.cpp")
big_transpose<-function(bigm) {
            new_ptr<-big.matrix(nrow=ncol(bigm),ncol=nrow(bigm),type="double")
            BigArmaT(bigm@address ,new_ptr@address)
            return(new_ptr)
                        }

set.seed(4)
m <- matrix(rnorm(1000*2000), nrow=1000)
bigm <- as.big.matrix(m,type="double")


t_big<-big_transpose(bigm)
t_m<-t(as.matrix(bigm))
all.equal(t_m,as.matrix(t_big))
```

> [1] TRUE

I find my attempts not efficient for 2 reasons:

1. I need to create a second `big.matrix` inside the R code. Is
   there a way to create the external pointer to the new `big.matrix`
   object inside c++ ?
2. To make work `memcpy` I had to create a loop.
       How to copy the matrix all at once?

Comment: Pardon my briefness and frankness but you are having elementary issues here, and I suggest you buckle up and study [eg some existing examples](http://gallery.rcpp.org) in some detail.

Comment: I can't find an example where the output is a Big.Matrix

Comment: Strange because they [are right there on them intertubes](https://www.google.com/search?q=Rcpp+and+bigmemory+big.matrix)

Comment: The Top 4 results are solutions that don't generate a big.matrix. In the internet are there similar results like my solution, but I couldn't find something that work with armadillo and avoids a final loop. My example works good and is replicable. My question was about how to improve it. Thank you anyway for give me google results, very helpfull

Comment: So you have a problem / use case with an (advanced) constructor for (Rcpp)Armadillo, and that too has been discussed [a bazillion times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896324/how-to-share-common-memory-in-armadillo).